# Problems with my ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm putting a finishing touch on my report.
But trying to fix my ToC caused it to be weird. For some reason, I had a page number on one of the pages of my 2-page ToC. Now it looks like this:

[image]

This is my code

```
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
```

Anyone know why it cuts so weird between the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with new margins for this specific page.

```
\newgeometry{top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=20mm, left=20mm}
\tableofcontents

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\restoregeometry
```